# Laravel 5.6. A small part of blade file not updated in cache

Tags: laravel, caching, view, laravel-blade

I have a blade view file in my project.

The HTML structure is something like :

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
<div>
```

The problem is that whenever I update anything inside class `c`, the changes are not rendered.

I have cleared configuration cache as well as view cache as :

> php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache
>
> php artisan view:clear && php artisan view:cache

This doesn't help either.

Upon further inspection, I found out that, the cache file in `/project_root/storage/framework/views` is separately kept for a specific part of the page only, in my case the div with class `c`.

I have no idea how it ended up keeping a separate cache for a small segment of a page. Can anybody suggest me a solution.

**EDIT :** I have tried deleting the entire cache folder `/project_root/storage/framework/views` as well in vain.

Other relevant informations :

Hosted server : Nginx on ubuntu

The sendfile option in `nginx.conf` is `ON`. If this is relevant.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski no Adam. I have tried all the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- clear browser cache
- check permissions to storage directory (it should be 777)
- be sure that your css is compiled (if you use webpack, laravel mix or gulp or something else)
- check if your css is loaded with your changes
- change css file name (read about notation `main.css?3.4.1` - each time when you make change in css or js it changes value after "?")

After change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=3.4.2">
```

And:

```
<?php $cssVersion = "3.4.2"; ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css?v=<?php echo $cssVersion; ?>">
```

**If you use PHP Storm:**

1. open menu File → Settings
2. go to Deployment → Options section
3. then uncheck option Preserve files timestamps

Good luck!

Comment: I have disabled cache for this site. The permission for the storage directory is 777. I don't use any of webpack, laravel mix or gulp. As my changes are in Html only, and I can see the Html when I view the page source. Still not fixed.

Comment: Change name of css file as I wrote

Comment: even if I am not making any changes in the CSS? I have tried and renamed the blade file already.

Comment: You also tried manually deleting the views hash stored in the storage on server?

Comment: Take a look, i updated answer - the case if you use php storm

Comment: I dont use phpStorm but.

Comment: Please check that css file deploy on server (maybe this file is in .gitignore... ?)